# How to install RTL8188FTV driver on Lubuntu 16.04 WITHOUT INTERNET?

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, lubuntu, internet

I've searched the internet many times but I've just found some drivers that **need internet for installation.**

I haven't any access to internet on this **Lubuntu 16.04** machine.
What's the solution??

The network card is ***RTL8188FTV***.

**AND** can I update to the latest version of Lubuntu and have internet connection with this network card?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107142/discussion-on-question-by-amir-hossein-maher-how-to-install-rtl8188ftv-driver-on).

Comment: FYI: Lubuntu 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (https://lubuntu.me/xenial-5-released/ http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` or your own system to confirm this is the case. I suggest you move to a supported release of Lubuntu for security reasons, unless you're off-line or are aware of risks.

Comment: The latest release of Lubuntu also uses LXQt, a different desktop to the legacy release of Lubuntu (which used LXDE), and an upgrade was not supported as issues need to be manually resolved by end-users. The easiest method *by far* is just a re-install (16.04 was only tested to upgrade to 16.10 (next release), or 18.04 (next LTS), the latest now is Lubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=268551 This is a topic about the driver. Click the link in the last post. There's a link to a github repo. Just copy the code to an USB stick. It should not need an internet connection.